# Xcode: Working In ARC and NSArrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, memory-management, nsarray

Okay so I know ARC auomatically releases objects in memory that don't have at least one retained pointer linked to it so just to clarify, if I were initialize object, `objectA`, inside a local block of code, then add it to a global array, `_objects`, and then proceed to remove `objectA` from that array outside of the scope in which `objectA` was initialized, would ARC automatically release `objectA` from memory, because I don't intend to ever refer to it again. See the example below

```
@implementation MXViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _objects = [@[] mutableCopy];
    NSObject *objectA = [NSObject new];
    [_objects addObject:objectA];
    NSObject *objectB = [NSObject new];
    [_objects addObject:objectB];
}

- (void)someMethod {
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    // since objectA has no retained 
    // pointers linked to it, will it be 
    // released from memory as expected
    // by ARC?
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would.  Arrays retain objects added to them, and release them when they are removed.  Here is your example code with reference counts in comments:

```
@implementation MXViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _objects = [@[] mutableCopy];
    NSObject *objectA = [NSObject new];    //objectA has a reference count of 1
    [_objects addObject:objectA];    //objectA now has a reference count of 2
    NSObject *objectB = [NSObject new];
    [_objects addObject:objectB];
}    //objectA's reference count is 1 because it is out of scope

- (void)someMethod {
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:0];    //objectA's reference count is 0 and it is deallocated
    // since objectA has no retained 
    // pointers linked to it, will it be 
    // released from memory as expected
    // by ARC?
}
```

Comment: So does the reference count of objectA automatically get reduced by 1 when viewDidLoad finishes executing because it was defined in that scope?

Comment: @Savagewood Yes, ARC releases objects when they go out of scope because a reference was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be released in your example. To be sure: make a subclass of NSObject for which you implement the dealloc method; log something therein, and add objects of that type instead of NSObject to your array. Prove it to yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you add the object to the array, the retain count is incremented (the array retains the object). After removing the object from the array, the retain count will drop to zero and the object will be released.

It's important to understand that the release won't necessarily occur *immediately* after the object is removed from the array. If you were to access the removed object in your someMethod property, ARC would postpone the release of the object accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be deallocated.

The "history" of the file would be something like

+1 (alloc) (reference counter:1) - From the "NSObject *objectA = [NSObject new];" instruction
+1 (retain) (reference counter:2) - "[_objects addObject:objectA];"
-1 (autorelease) (reference counter:1) - At some unknown point that we don't need to know
-1 (release) (reference counter:0) - "[_objects removeObjectAtIndex:0];"

And, of course, when it gets to 0, it will be deallocated.

Comment: That was my other question, when does the autorelease occur? Just out of curiosity. Hopefully right after the last reference to it but that's a compiler task

Comment: From my understanding, there is an NSAutoreleasePool instance internally created by iOS framework, in which Objects are put in when an autorelease is called (in this case, the autorelease is called when you create your Object), and periodically checks if the Object is still needed - meaning, the scope in which the autorelease has been called is still "active".